# Make object static and still assign and change it

Tags: javascript, object

I want to use a static object, assign it to a new variable and change it.

```
var MY_STATIC: {message: "I am static"};
var test = MY_STATIC;

test.message = "I am not static enough";

console.log(MY_STATIC.messsage);  ==> I am not static enough
```

But I want MY_STATIC.message to be still "I am static" to use it later again. 
How can I make the object stay the same allthough I assign and change it

Comment: have you tried declaring it as `var MY_STATIC: {var message: "I am static"};`

Comment: you can set the object property to be locked and not writable with  `defineProperty()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Do you mean _static_ or _const_

Comment: @Proto Bassi do you know that `var test = MYSTATIC;` should be `var test = MY_STATIC;` and is missing the '_' in the name?

Comment: object properties are interesting, but as I do have several objects and several keys, this makes it a bit unreadable. Plus the objects are already part of an object and I would need to initialize the objects in another method. Still good point.

Comment: @James Thorpe: you are right, I was talking about constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `Object.create()` in order to create a new instanse of `MY_STATIC` object:

```js
var MY_STATIC = {message: "I am static"};
var test = Object.create(MY_STATIC);
test.message = "I am not static enough";

console.log(test.message);
console.log(MY_STATIC.message);
```

Answer (score 1):

On an ES5-compatible engine, you can ["freeze" an object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.9):

```js
var static = Object.freeze({message: "I am static"});
snippet.log(static.message); // "I am static"
static.message = "Not!";
snippet.log(static.message); // "I am static"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `obj1=obj2` you are passing them by ref. What u need here is to pass them by value, so use this code

```
 var MY_STATIC = {message:"Static I am"};

 function Clone(x) {
    for(prop in x)
    this[prop] = (typeof(x[prop]) == 'object')? 
                  new Clone(x[prop]) : x[prop];
 }

 (function(x){
     var test  = new Clone(x);
     test.message = 'Not static';
 })(MY_STATIC)
```